# Unshift array method slow downs Dom listing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanna replace img src using array unshift method, while doing this process the previous image is shown from 2 to 3 seconds and then replace my new image url

```
   var data = {"id":"124", "url":"img.jpg"};
   var data1 = {"id":"1234", "url":"img1.png"};
   var array = [data];
   array.unshift(data1);
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="data in array"> 
<img ng-src = data.url /> 
</div>
```

I have expected the new data comes without any delay, and never shown the previous image url, but unfortunately i faced the problem of previous image data load first then change the new one.

Comment: Post your src replacement code too

Comment: What you mean by `data.url` and `data1, data2`? Really confused!. pls check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RameshRajendran that is image url, i misspelled.

Comment: @CharlieH is my question is wrong?

Comment: It was not clear without the edit

Comment: Where are you executing the code? I mean in which event?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will works for you.

```html
<img class="imageLoad ng-hide" ng-src = data.url />
```

```
$(".imageLoad").load(function() {
  // Image loaded do action
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete){
       $(this).load();
       (or use, if you have class ng-hide)
       $(".imageLoad").removeClass('ng-hide');
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey yeah, i tried this too, but the image src is take a 2 second to load new image_url, So that the previous image is shows first and then replace the new one. Is any other options are there for fast loading the data ? @Aswin